# как посчитать количество итераций рекурсивной функции С++

Tags: c++, функции, рекурсия

как посчитать кол-во итераций в рекурсивной функции без использования ссылок, указателей, областей видимости и вывести в консоль на примере кода снизу

(функция считает число Фибоначчи под номером N)

```
int FibRec(int N)
{ 
    if (N == 2)
        return 1;
    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    return FibRec(N - 2) + FibRec(N - 1);
}
```

буду очень благодарен за помощь!

PS:

вот код всей программы

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int FibRec(int N)
{
    if (N == 2)
        return 1;
    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    return FibRec(N - 2) + FibRec(N - 1);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int N;
        cout << "N" << i << " = ";
        cin >> N;
        cout << FibRec(N) << endl;
    }
    return 0;
}
```

цель программы посчитать 5 чисел Фибоначчи и узнать кол-во итераций затраченных на это

Comment: Добавьте поле-счётчик в класс и считайте

Comment: задание для университета и есть ограничения в синтаксисе. нужно максимально простое и быстрое решение

Comment: предлагаете угадать ваши ограничения? Максимально простое и быстрое решение что то считать - добавить счетчик.

Comment: просто я не очень понимаю как этот счетчик организовать так, чтобы функция выводила это значение, так как return уже занят рекурсией

Comment: вывести из функции у вас не получится, так как у вас эта функция будет много много раз вызываться с одними и теми же параметрами. Вызывайте свою функцию, а уже после того как она отработает, выводите значение счетчика.

Comment: По-простому - сделайте глобальную переменную счётчика

Comment: в этом и проблема что работа требует отсутствие чего либо кроме рекурсий и функций, то есть нельзя выходить за область видимости функции, а выводить из нее значения только через return

Comment: Описать рекурсивную функцию FibRec(N) целого типа, вычисляющую N-е число Фибоначчи F(N) по формуле: F(1) = F(2) = 1, F(k) = F(k–2) + F(k–1), k = 3, 4, ... С помощью этой функции найти пять чисел Фибоначчи с указанными номерами и вывести эти числа вместе с количеством рекурсивных вызовов функции FibRec, потребовавшихся для их нахождения.


до этого курс предусматривает только ввод вывод из консоли, функции и их параметры и рекурсивные функции.


можно пользоваться только базовыми условиями  if и циклами for while.

Comment: очевидно можно было бы воспользоваться областями видимости и ссылками но курс не позволяет что очень усложняет решение

Comment: @MBo прошу прощения не понял сначала что вы имели ввиду, если вы имели ввиду счетчик за пределами всех функций то правда как вариант, спасибо!

Comment: Так мы с этого счетчика и начали 

Comment: Используйте для ответов форму ответов, не нужно редактировать вопрос ответом, (а уж тем более помечать в заголовке как "РЕШЕНО", для этого можно дать ответ на свой вопрос в форме ответа и пометить свой же ответ как верный

Comment: @tym32167 да извините изначально не дошло. спасибо за ответ

Answer (score 0, accepted):

можно воспользоваться публичной переменной-счетчиком и внутри функции поставить инкремент чтобы при каждой итерации счетчик увеличивался на единицу

```
int counter = 0; // счетчик 
int FibRec(int N)
{
    counter++; //инкремент
    if (N == 2)
        return 1;
    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    return FibRec(N - 2) + FibRec(N - 1);
}
```

таким образом при завершении функции мы получим переменную содержащую кол-во итерации затраченных на выполнение данной функции которую мы сможем использовать далее в коде

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int counter = 0;
int FibRec(int N)
{
    counter++;
    if (N == 2)
        return 1;
    if (N == 1)
        return 1;
    return FibRec(N - 2) + FibRec(N - 1);
}

int main()
{
    for (int i = 0; i < 5; i++) {
        int N;
        cout << "N" << i+1 << " = ";
        cin >> N;
        cout << FibRec(N) << endl;
    }
    cout << "how iter = " << counter << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

вывод:

```
N1 = 4
3
N2 = 5
5
N3 = 3
2
N4 = 4
3
N5 = 7
13
how iter = 47
```